# Police car chase dataset

Tags: data-request, police

I'm looking for a dataset of police car (or motorbike) chases containing for each chase as many following labels as possible:

- date
- start time and end time
- start location and end location
- path taken by the chased car
- casualties (police, civilians, and crook)
- type of car used by the crook
- reason for fleeing
- weather (especially temperature and precipitation)
- number of policemen, police cars (with types of car), police choppers and other police vehicles involved
- was it broadcasted live on TV?

I'm especially interested in the US.

Comment: I cannot say that this is an answer, that's why I put it in a comment. Here is a report for a dataset almost similar with yours. They use data from IACP Police Pursuit Database. Maybe if you read the report, you will find something usefull http://pursuitsafety.org/images/IACP%20Pursuits.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Suffolk Police Department's annual reports document most of this data, but only for a couple of years. pretty sure they have it for 2006-2008 or 2009. you'll have to check, but the data is there:
http://www.suffolkva.us/spd/inside/annualreports/